# JDBC MySQL store emojis without utf8mb4 encoding

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Trace:

> 2016-09-26 06:52:43.756  WARN 1280 --- [  XNIO-2 task-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1366, SQLState: HY000
>   2016-09-26 06:52:43.756 ERROR 1280 --- [  XNIO-2 task-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x80\x84' for column 'name' at row 1

I understand that MySQL doesn't want to store emoji and I should change the encoding to `utf8mb4`, but is there a way just to store a string '\xF0\x9F\x80\x84' and not ''?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to encode/decode values stored into that field. If you consider for instance [MimeUtility](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeUtility.html) to do it, most of your (latin) characters would still be readable:

```
st.setString(1, MimeUtility.encodeWord(nameWithEmoji));
```

ann retrieve wich

```
String nameWithEmoji = MimeUtility.decodeWprd(rs.getString("name"));
```